# Unpivot data in Google Sheets with Query Function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have data in a spreadsheet that is being pulled and refreshed through the Salesforce connector that looks like this:

| Person | State | LA ORDR | LA RTRN | HA ORDR | HA RTRN | MO ORDR | MO RTRN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carly | GA | 3 | 5 | 20 | 10 | 3 | 1 |
| Megan | GA | 4 | 5 | 32 | 12 | 3 | 2 |
| Jenny | TN | 5 | 5 | 32 | 11 | 4 | 3 |

I am trying to unpivot the data so that I end up with:

| Person | State | Product | ORDR | RTRN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carly | GA | LA | 3 | 5 |
| Carly | GA | HA | 20 | 10 |
| Carly | TN | MO | 3 | 1 |
| Megan | GA | LA | 4 | 5 |
| Megan | GA | HA | 32 | 12 |

I was able to successfully get to this:

| Person | State | ORDR | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Carly | GA | 3 | LA |
| Carly | GA | 20 | HA |
| Carly | TN | 3 | MO |
| Megan | GA | 4 | LA |
| Megan | GA | 32 | HA |

Using this formula:

```
={
QUERY(A1:E8, "select A, B, C, 'LA' label C 'ORDR', 'LA' 'Product'", 1);
QUERY(A1:E8, "select A, B, D, 'HA' offset 1 label 'HA' ''", 0);
QUERY(A1:E8, "select A, B, E, 'MO' offset 1 label 'MO' ''", 0)
}
```

I can't seem to figure out if it possible to add in the additional column RTRN. Anyone help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alternative Option

Alternatively, you could also take advantage of the built-in scripting in Google Sheets to create a custom `=unpivot()` formula for a cleaner usage of the formula in your spreadsheet file. Please see the sample script below.

> *You may follow the steps in [creating & saving a custom function in Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#creating_a_custom_function).*

### ***[UPDATED]** Sample custom formula script*

```
function unpivot(range) {
  //Filter Person in A, State in E, LA Order in L, LA RTRN in N, HA ORDR in O, HA RTRN in Q, MO ORDR in R, and MO RTRN in T
  const indices = [0, 4, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19];
  range = range.map(row => row.filter((_, index) => indices.includes(index)));

  var rawData = range.map((data, index) => index > 0 && data.map((x, i) => i > 1 && [range[0][i].split(' ')[0], range[0][i].split(' ')[1], x, data[0], data[1]]).filter(x => x)).filter(y => y).flat();
  var container = [['Person', 'State', 'Product', 'ORDR', 'RTRN']];
  rawData.forEach((d, i, arr) => {
    try {
      d[0] == arr[i + 1][0] && d[3] == arr[i + 1][3] && d[4] == arr[i + 1][4] && container.push([d[3], d[4], d[0], d[2], arr[i + 1][2]])
    } catch { }
  });
  return container;
}
```

### *Demo*

> *Using the `=unpivot()` custom function.*

[image]

### *Reference*

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [JavaScript Array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [JavaScript Array filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [JavaScript Array forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [JavaScript flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: This is super helpful! I've been trying to adjust without much luck, so thought I'd ask - how do I modify this custom function if there are additional data columns that are in the data set, but not part of the final output. In the full data set, I have Person in A, State in E, LA Order in L, LA RTRN in N, HA ORDR in O, HA RTRN in Q, MO ORDR in R, and MO RTRN in T?

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated the script to filter and process data according to the specific column locations based on the data you have provided:
`Person` in column A
`State` in column E
`LA Order` in column L
`LA Return` in column N
`HA Order` in column O
`HA Return` in column Q
`MO Order` in column R
`MO Return` in column T

Answer (score 3):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(rep_,A2:B, grp_,C2:H, header_,index(left(C1:H1,2)), size_,2,
     Σ,reduce(wraprows(,columns(rep_)+1+size_,),sequence(columns(grp_)/size_,1,1,size_),lambda(a,c,{a;{rep_,wrapcols(index(header_,c),rows(rep_),index(header_,c)),choosecols(grp_,sequence(size_,1,c))}})),
     Λ,filter(Σ,index(Σ,,column(rep_))<>""),sort(Λ,xmatch(index(Λ,,1),index(rep_,,1)),1))
```

- *Adjust the ranges in the first line of the formula as needed*

[image]